# Wordpress: I customized a template on localhost uploaded it but I want to purchase the same of premium template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I downloaded a free wordpress template, after customized it and use it , I want to purchase a premium template the same as i used for free. My question is, the free template and it's content will remain or I should start to customize the new template.

Comment: "My question is, the free template and its content will remain or should I start to customize the new template?"

Answer: The edits you made will not change as long as you will not update that theme. I suggest you read and practice this https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes.

With the premium template part, you should take it as a separate theme (basically you are using the free version of the theme, it means that its premium version has additional features/plugin etc. in it) so you have to do the customization all over again.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't customize the theme's files at all, because you will run into this exact problem: every upgrade means you have to re-do the customization.

Instead, build a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), and make your child theme only overwrite the minimum required. This way, you will benefit from updates (especially security updates) of the parent theme, and will have very little work to do after upgrade, while you're still able to customize the code where needed.

If possible, use hooks, filters, and css, and you will have even less work even after major updates.